# Why did Vader board the disabled Rebel flagship at the end of Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the end of *Rogue One*, the Rebel flagship is disabled. From an exterior shot, we can see that it is heavily damaged in several locations. Vader then decides to *board* the ship.

**Why didn't he order his Star Destroyer (or the nearby Death Star) to blow it up? Knowing that the plans were beamed aboard the ship, wouldn't it have been more prudent to just destroy it?**

Comment: Ask risk the plans ending up in the debris field? I think not!

Comment: Would there have been any realistic chance of the storage media (computer memory banks... disc) surviving the explosion and being recoverrable afterwards?

Comment: Seems like a pretty big chance to take...

Comment: Maybe, they want the plans too? Tarkin did blow up the base. If they had no backup elsewhere, then the only plans left are the ones the Rebels stole.

Comment: @zack_falcon do you want to add that as an answer? that makes sense. maybe vader wanted to analyse the plans, on suspicion that Galen Erso had made a weakness...

Comment: I have no actual evidence on this, so I'm not sure if it could be an answer - perhaps someone with more knowledge / sources on that can. If that was the only copy though, it would also make sense as to why the Rebels would charge in on a heavily guarded planet as opposed to some remote server system elsewhere.

Comment: Come to think of it, if that was the only plan in existence, then Vader chasing down the Tantive IV and his Star Destroyer attempting to capture escape pods instead of blowing them all up might make sense.

Comment: @zack_falcon Please add this as an answer. Even though it's speculative, I think it holds weight. Others can comment on the answer if they can add facts.

Comment: This line of thinking breaks verisimilitude for me. I can buy giant planet killing lasers, but there is no way there's only one copy of plans for a project to create a space station the size of a small moon.

Comment: @Paul, that's why I'm hesitant to add it as answer. It's mostly speculation. If there was any other copy though, I would've thought it prudent for the Rebels to go for those copies. IIRC, Galen Erso also made a point of mentioning "complete engineering archive", which I would think implies if there are any other plans, they aren't as complete, or it's the only one he knows of.

Comment: @vikingsteve we have external hard drives that are military rated to survive high impact and high temperatures... You can even drop them while writing and not lose data - the GFFA probably has similar tech

Comment: @Paul it's unthinkable now, but the original story was written around 1970s tech.

Comment: @Erik, the original movie never claimed it was the only copy; it is believable that they'd want to capture the ship for other reasons (see where else it was transmitted to, make sure they actually had them, etc. ). I was addressing specifically this comment as it posits that it was because the Empire wanted the plans back because they had no other copies.

Comment: @Paul hm, I think I misread one of the comments. It would make sense for that to be only copy the rebels have; it indeed makes no sense for it to be the only copy still in existence, which is what the comment alludes to.

Comment: One possibility is that the only copies of the plans are on the death star itself. Then one has multiple copies of the plans, but it still makes sense to go after the planet (as opposed to the even more guarded death star). Though then the question remains when (and to where) the plans where transferred before the death star blew up in A New Hope

Comment: [The Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool): Because the ensuing scene would be awesome.

Comment: The plans aren't the only useful thing on the ship.  Once he verifies that the plans have been recovered, there will presumably be a few crew members with which he might discuss the location of the hidden rebel base.

Comment: @Valorum On the other hand, plans floating in space are probably more easily recovered than plans in the hands of people shooting at you. Your answer provides a much more convincing reason.

Comment: @zack_falcon about the "complete engineering archive" I interpret that with more meaning. It's unthinkable that this are the only plans of the Death Star, but maybe is the only plans with the weakness revealed, at least that is what I think when he said "complete", but I maybe wrong

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization)), some murmur in the Force warned Vader not to simply order its destruction. The *implication* is that he unconsciously shied away from murdering his daughter.

> *Vader stared at the burning ship. There was death at play, suffering and fear, yes—and **something entirely different. Something that repelled his withered, agonized flesh.***
>
> *“Prepare a boarding party,” he said.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization))</sup></sub>

---

I would assume that from a purely logistical point of view, Vader also wanted to double-check that additional copies hadn't been made or transmitted. This is the same reason that he boards Leia's ship at the start of New Hope.

Comment: Just laughing at, "the same reason."

Comment: I really need to read some of these novelisations. Seems like they clear up a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Devsman - They're a good read and well-recommended.

Comment: Uhm did he already know that they had something aboard that ship at that time? (I mean he just arrived to a general alert that an attack was underway)

Comment: @Thomas - "*The rebel flagship is disabled, my lord,” the Devastator’s captain reported crisply at Vader’s side. Darth Vader did not turn to him as he spoke. “But **it has received transmissions from the surface.”"*** - It doesn't take a genius to work out what the rebels stole

Comment: ah kk didn't notice that when I watched the film tnx!

Answer (score 12):

Why rely on deductions and assumptions when there's hard evidence to be gained, and an imbalance of power that minimizes risk?

Taking the ship and its occupants mostly intact preserves multiple avenues for gleaning hard evidence:

- Interrogating personnel
- Analyzing ships logs/system auditing trails, notably any transmissions
- Recovering and cataloging the actual data acquired (potentially a subset of the data transmitted even if that information is already known)

Exercising these options can more clearly establish the scope of the leak and thus narrow focus of any hardening/counterintelligence operations required to  identify and secure any vulnerabilities that were exposed, as well as assess Rebel awareness and capacity to capitalize on those vulnerabilities.

There's also potential to gather additional, unrelated inteligence in the process such as: fleet movement, base locations, security codes, operational procedures, and overall enemy strength.

Comment: Yes, this -- taking rebel prisoners, torturing and interrogating rebels and gaining and understanding of the structure of the rebellion, who's involved, what systems have allied with the rebellion, etc. etc. A treasure trove of intelligence on the rebellion. Why just blow it up?

Comment: There's even an argument to be made that the rebel ship should have initiated a self-destruct to protect any secrets it might reveal.  I believe that angle has come up at least once in the Star Trek universe, though specific examples elude my recall.

Comment: In addition, I'm guessing that Vader wasn't too happy about being bested by a handful of Rebels who were able to pass the plans through the crack in the doorway even as he slaughtered their shipmates. I imagine he wanted to inflict some pain on those aboard. And he DID choke that guy to death once aboard (as opposed to taking him prisoner).

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** Chopping up Rebels with your lightsaber is more fun than watching their ship be destroyed by turbolasers.

**Long answer:** Vader is consistently shown to react emotionally and place a high priority on his own agenda. He often does what he wants to do, rather than always doing what is most strategically sensible. For one thing, he's the second highest ranking person in the largest military in the galaxy and yet chooses to fly a starfighter in the Battle of Yavin. Can you imagine the Vice President of the U.S. flying a fighter plane into battle during his term in office? Perhaps he's the best pilot on the Death Star, but that implies that he pilots regularly, which isn't something you'd expect from such a high-ranking figure.

Likewise, Vader participates directly in the ground invasion of Hoth. I don't think he's on the front lines, but he is among the troopers that storm the rebel base. He also boards the Tantive IV at the beginning of ANH. He personally confronts Han and Leia at Cloud City, giving Han an opportunity to take a shot at him. Vader isn't just a commander, he's a fighter. He clearly enjoys combat and personally takes part in every operation we see under his command. He is not the type to sit back and watch the gunners cut apart the enemy ship.

You could also ask why he boards Leia's disabled ship at the beginning of *A New Hope*. The answer is the same.

Comment: @Möoz Seriously? **Q:** Why did Vader board the disabled Rebel flagship at the end of Rogue One? **A:** Chopping up rebels with your lightsaber is fun.

Comment: You could have at least mentioned the cinematic angle and the chance to have a dark moment right at the end of the movie...

Comment: @Möoz Just because my answer is humorous doesn't mean it is invalid. In fact, I think my answer is more realistic than answers based on military strategy. Vader is consistently shown to react emotionally and place a high priority on his own agenda. For one thing, he's the second highest ranking person in the largest military in the galaxy and yet chooses to fly a starfighter in the Battle of Yavin. Can you imagine the Vice President of the U.S. flying a fighter plan into battle during his term in office?

Comment: @vikingsteve I was going for short and sweet since this question already has an accepted answer

Comment: @Möoz You shouldn't be reviewing answers if you can't take a few seconds to accurately assess the answer.

Comment: @user45623 the king of Jordan and the Prime Minister of Israel have both flown combat missions. Why dont you flesh out your answer a bit and Ill remove my downvote.

Comment: @vikingsteve Did they fly combat missions **while they were in office**? Your question asks about "prudent" behavior, which makes it sound like an in-universe question. Since you didn't ask for an out-of-universe answer and clearly have some ideas in that direction already, I'm not going to waste my time expanding my answer with an out-of-universe perspective just to get you to remove your capricious downvote.

Comment: We love jokes on Stack Exchange! :) However, they're better as comments, they're not accepted as answers.

Comment: @Bellatrix See my response to Mooz

Comment: Ok its a nice answer now, upvoted.

Comment: @user45623 Believe me, I for one tend to post most of the 'jokes' and humorous answers, the only thing is that this sounded (in its original form) as a comment and didn't seem to me that it was trying to be serious. This fleshed-out form is much improved.

Comment: @user45623 Additionally, I *do* take great care in performing proper review actions and lean toward to 'skip' button more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

Vader is a professional. He doesn't leave things to chance, he sees things to the end, himself. When he becomes involved, it will he his hand force-choking the information out of the captured enemies. He doesn't delegate, he doesn't trust blasters, or cannons. He's learned through experience the likelihood of a small thing escaping huge destruction.

C'mon, how many near death experiences had Anakin had as a jedi? How many exploding capital ships should have been the end of all things for him? He probably felt someone with the power of the force somewhere on board. Why else was he on his way to the Tantive IV? There wasn't even proof the plans were on there. But he *felt* something. And by this point, Vader trusts his feelings for these things, aged Sith he be.